# Keep and discard at the same time with purrr

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

The package `purrr` defines two functions `keep()` and `discard()` which do as their names suggest based on a predicate.

I cannot find a function in this package which separates a list/vector based on a predicate. For example:

```
v <- 1:10
separate(v, function(x) x %% 2 == 0)
```

which would return:

```
list(no = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), yes = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
```

Do I miss something? I think it could be more efficient than to call two functions that will go through the entire list.

---

EDIT: I want to do that with a list and a more complex function to apply on each element. So I am not sure that it could be done with `split`.

for example:

```
l1 <- list(list(1, 2, 3), list(4, 5), list(6))
purrr::discard(l1, ~ length(.) == 3)
```

Comment: You might be looking for `split()`: `split(v, v %% 2 == 0)`.

Comment: dplyr has `group_split`; however, it works with data frames or lists.  `seq(10) %>% data.frame %>% group_split(even = . %% 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

`split` function in base R does that :

```
v <- 1:10
split(v, v %% 2 == 0)

#$`FALSE`
#[1] 1 3 5 7 9

#$`TRUE`
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

---

You can write a condition and use it to create two separate lists.

```
v <- 1:10
inds <- v %% 2 == 0
list(yes = v[inds], no = v[!inds])
```

and

```
l1 <- list(list(1, 2, 3), list(4, 5), list(6))
inds <- lengths(l1) == 3
list(yes = l1[inds], no = l1[!inds])
```

Comment: Yes, it does as shown in the second example.

Comment: But it does not answer the question, which is how to apply a predicate to a list, Here you have to use another function `lengths` with an `s` it cannot be done for any function which can be applied to the element of a list....

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a logical vector as a recycling vector to do the split

```
split(v, c(TRUE, FALSE))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It does not even work.... `split(v, c(FALSE, TRUE)` will do the trick. Nevertheless it does not answer the question at all....

Comment: @pietrodito I was just showing a method to split it.  You can do it eitherway